How to set up raspberry pi DNS with static IP from internet provider

I want to be independent from hosts and their fees with raspberry pi for small projects.
What I'm trying to do

Create a spring boot app which would be accessible from domain
Make it work with https via Certbot and Let's Encript
have a subdomain on it like console.mydomain.com or admin.mydomain.com

What I can do:

Buy static IP address from Internet provider
Buy domain and set it to point to the static IP
Buy Raspberry pi's
Program Spring boot + Thymleaf + Vue ( Not that I can't program in anything else, I have chosen this stack for small projects )
Have access to the router

What I don't know:

After I bought the static IP, what do I have to do in the router, if any
If only I install certbot on Raspberry pi will it work and make my spring boot work with https? ( Along with spring configs... )
After I configured the router, in order to create subdomains for my projects or DNS server, what should I do ( By subdomain for DNS I mean e.g. dns.amazon.org but with my domain )




Thank you in advance for your patience


NOTE: Please do not send links which doesn't have full answer and if you do Please provide the rest in your answer
What I know:
I think I should setup a dedicated Raspberry pi for DNS server but for most of these kinds of projects I'm responsible for, there is only one Raspberry pi. So let me know if I can do all in one as well.


You will need to setup "port forwarding" on the router to the raspberry pi. There are lots of guides to doing this on the internet and will likely be specific to your router.

I'm not sure of Spring boot can be configured with HTTPS as I've never used it. However if you use NGINX as suggested below, you can add SSL to the config quite easily.

If you want multiple projects running, look at setting up NGINX and configuring a reverse proxy.


A reverse proxy means that all your sites can have different URLs, but come to the same service / IP address. NGINX will then filter them out and point them on to the correct destinations.
Documentation for reverse proxy: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

I marked it as answer, how ever I was hoping any solution without the help of nginx. I'm thinking of an OP approach like using dnsmasq. If you knew any better feel free to share it here. @Interwebber

@MohammadAsgari - I'm not familiar with dnsmasq, but I believe it is just helps manage DNS, which isn't going to help you here. As you a planning on connecting from outside your network, you will all be going to one IP address for all the services, so you'll need  some sort of reverse proxy. If you need more help with that, might be worth opening a question on a more relevant site.
